# How to implement google indoor floor map of one building in my android activity with all floor picker options

Tags: android, android-studio, google-indoor-maps

I would like to get a google indoor floor map of a building in my android app using android studio, so that when ever i open the app, it should show me the building location automatically zooming to it and should display the floor picker option too.Later, i would like to customize that map by adding specific markers on required floors. Is this possible ? How to achieve this ?
                  My doubt is that, is there any API's keys to be downloaded & Enabled other than Google maps Android API. And also, is there any special coding required for this indoor floor map of a building to get floor picker on the activity. What will be the java code pattern to achieve this task without any complications ?

Any Suggestions and advice's are appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I got it. I selected GoogleMap Activity instead of selecting blank activity and it just created an google map fragment XML file. For getting indoor building i just wrote some java code to move the camera position to the building by specifying latitude & longitude of it. On zooming to the building which is having floors information on google, floorpicker is automatically showed and then we can toggle it. This google map fragment is having direction compass,zoom controls,GPS enable button on it. We can enable or disable them pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable or enable the level picker control by calling

```
GoogleMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(boolean);
```

This is useful if you want to replace the default level picker with your own.